# ansible export selected results to CSV

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which gathers information for the operating system version of all cluster nodes for a number of clusters but I need to extract and transpose it if possible in a table with headers. I am only interested in two values: 'name','version.full' - how can this be accomplished? The variable ontap_version_info contains the output from all clusters below.

```yaml
---
- name: NetApp ONTAP Version Reporting
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  collections:
    - netapp.ontap

  vars:
    pp_ontap_clusters:
      - cls1
      - cls2
      - cls3
      - cls4
      - cls5
      - cls6
      - cls7

  tasks:
  - name: run ONTAP gather facts for certificate info with specified fields
    netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
      hostname: "{{ item }}"
      username: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_usr') }}"
      password: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_pwd') }}"
      use_rest: always
      https: true
      validate_certs: false
      gather_subset:
        - security/certificates
      fields:
        - 'name'
        - 'version'
    loop: "{{ pp_ontap_clusters }}"
    register: ontap_version_info
```

Below is a sample output from a single cluster as an example where I am only interested in the full version

```json
"item": "cls1",
    "ontap_info": {
        "cluster/nodes": {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "/api/cluster/nodes?max_records=1024&fields=name%2Cversion"
                }
            },
            "num_records": 2,
            "records": [
                {
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/cluster/nodes/578658e0-87fc-11e9-b8bd-00a098f2ea00"
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "cls1-node1",
                    "uuid": "578658e0-87fc-11e9-b8bd-00a098f2ea00",
                    "version": {
                        "full": "NetApp Release 9.13.1: Mon Jun 19 13:36:41 UTC 2023",
                        "generation": 9,
                        "major": 13,
                        "minor": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/cluster/nodes/6aae0abe-a410-11e9-ae1d-00a098f2ea72"
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "cls1-node2",
                    "uuid": "6aae0abe-a410-11e9-ae1d-00a098f2ea72",
                    "version": {
                        "full": "NetApp Release 9.13.1: Mon Jun 19 13:36:41 UTC 2023",
                        "generation": 9,
                        "major": 13,
                        "minor": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below expressions

```yaml
name_version_query: '[].ontap_info."cluster/nodes".records[].[name, version.full]'
name_version_list: "{{ ontap_version_info.results|json_query(name_version_query) }}"
name_version_dict: "{{ dict(ontap_version_info.results|json_query(name_version_query)) }}"
```

give you the list

```yaml
name_version_list:
  - - cls1-node1
    - 'NetApp Release 9.13.1: Mon Jun 19 13:36:41 UTC 2023'
  - - cls1-node2
    - 'NetApp Release 9.13.1: Mon Jun 19 13:36:41 UTC 2023'
```

and the dictionary

```yaml
name_version_dict:
  cls1-node1: 'NetApp Release 9.13.1: Mon Jun 19 13:36:41 UTC 2023'
  cls1-node2: 'NetApp Release 9.13.1: Mon Jun 19 13:36:41 UTC 2023'
```